# What make an egg explode in the microwave

Tags: explosions, microwaves, food

I think it's related to the air pouch in the egg, but I'd like to have a full physics explanation. What are the forces in presence?

What are the tricks to prevent the explosion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is  a layman](http://www.clark.com/why-food-explodes-in-your-microwave) site about explosions in microwaves

Explosion happens when

> when water in the food is heated rapidly, producing steam.
>
> When there’s no way for the steam to escape, an explosion takes place.
>
> Anyy food that has a skin or membrane can explode in the microwave, according to Snider, a professor at the University of Delaware.
>
> Hot dogs, eggs and potatoes are just a few common examples.
>
> In order to reduce the odds of food exploding in your microwave, you want to give the steam a place to escape. Simply take a fork and pierce the food item several times, Snider suggests.

Microwave   ovens have frequencies specifically to raise the energy level of the water molecules which exist as part of  the lattice of edibles, in order to cook them. If the temperature of water goes over 100C it turns into steam. If steam cannot escape due to a mebrane , or the thick skin of the egg the pressure goes up, and continued heating generates an explosion.

To avoid exploding eggs, I think if you set them in a small bowl, crack them and stick a pin through the inner membrane the pressure will be relieved. I have not tried it. It is easier to boil them in water.

Comment: The problem is my egg explode, even when out of the eggshell. I really don't know why. I have to put a cover to prevent the microwave to get dirty.

Comment: There is a second membrane  around the white of the egg, and a third around the yolk. Both need to be pierced for steam to get through